# Help in evaluating an Integral over an interval

Tags: integration

So I have been given an Integral and its answer.

$$\int_4^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+16}\,\text{d}x$$

The book used Trig substitution and got the answer:

$${1\over 16}\left.\left(4\arctan\left({x\over 4}\right)\right)\right|_4^\infty$$*the last symbol means from $(4, \infty)$.

I know how to evaluate at 4, but I am having trouble finding out the integral at infinity. I am confused on how to evaluate and solve this when arctan goes to infinity? Please help.

Comment: Think about the graph of the arctan function.

Comment: **Hint :** $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent function means opposite over adjacent.  The arc-tangent function takes this ratio and gives the angle that gives this ratio.  So what does the triangle look like when the opposite is infinitely bigger than the adjacent?

[image]

Now just keep going, what angle is $\theta$ approaching?

> Hopefully you see that it approaches $90^\circ = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (you should *always* use radians when taking integrals involving angles).

Answer (score 1):

Arctangent approaches a limit value:

[image]

This is what you need to use in the limit of integration. Indeed:
$$
   \int_4^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+4^2} = \lim_{t \to \infty}  \int_4^t \frac{dx}{x^2+4^2} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{4}\arctan\frac{x}{4}\right]_{x=4}^{x=t}
$$